# how to change SKU validation message in order by sku tab in magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, inline-translations

I want to change SKU error message:

> Please enter valid SKU key

To

> Please enter a valid SKU key

in magento 2.1 , can anyone help me please.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to code? If so, you can change this translation in '`app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[theme]/i18n/en_US.csv`' and add this line in:

```
"Please enter valid SKU key","Please enter a valid SKU key",module,Magento_Ui
```

If you don't have this file, search for `i18n` folder in files, and en_US.csv.

EDIT: The working option was to create a file: `app/design/frontend/**VENDOR**/**THEME**/web/mage/validation‌​.js` and to change text there. Although the correct would be to find .csv with translate and translate it there.

Comment: thank you for reply, its not working, actually i have added theme in vendor folder , can any suggesions please

Comment: You can also change this text in `lib/web/mage/validation.js` where this text is originally - but this is the last solution. Try to search across the files for text `Please enter 6 or more characters. Leading and trailing spaces will be ignored.` - your text should be added in the same file as this text.

Comment: thank you, how to override this validation.js file in vendor folder magento_customer module, can u guide me please.

Comment: thanks you, its working, but i want to override this lib/web/mage/validation.js file in my theme in vendor folder in magento_customer module, how may i achieve this, can you help me.

Comment: I think it is the `app/design/frontend/**VENDOR**/**THEME**/web/mage/validation.js`, but I am not sure. Can you try it?

Comment: Good, could you mark as the correct answer?